# Grab http response header with curl

Tags: php, regex, curl

I use `curl --interface ip_goes here  -I -L https://www.youtube.com/` to get http headers but i want to store the `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` in a variable. I can do it with `preg_match` but i am wondering if there are more efficient solution

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 09 Jan 2015 05:49:12 GMT
Server: gwiseguy/2.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Expires: Tue, 27 Apr 1971 19:44:06 EST
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://support.google.com/accounts/answer/151657?hl=en for more info."
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block; report=https://www.google.com/appserve/security-bugs/log/youtube
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=0.02
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Set-Cookie: YSC=zCtzROldgfs; path=/; domain=.youtube.com; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE=Oz-yH5fLujM; expires=Wed, 09-Sep-2015 17:42:11 GMT; path=/; domain=.youtube.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this command

> curl --interface ip_goes_here -s -I -L https://www.youtube.com/ | head
>   -1

note additional -s for silent

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$str="HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 09 Jan 2015 05:49:12 GMT
Server: gwiseguy/2.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN 
more string....";
    $a=explode("\n",$str);
    var_dump($a[0]);
```

Output:
`string 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'`